# Не компилируются рисунки в LaTeX

Tags: latex

Работаю в TeXMaker. Подготовил документ. Компилируется всё, ошибок нет, но на месте рисунков пустые поля.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{uz_kgu}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\inputencoding{cp1251}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{figure}[!tbh]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.1, bb=3 10 83 53]{pic1} 
 \caption{Рисунок 1}
 \label{tempvoid1}
\end{figure}
...
```

Что может быть не так?

Comment: Уточните формат рисунка и какой командой пытаетесь компилировать. Волшебный шар говорит, что Вы пытаетесь рисунок в формате EPS компилировать командой `pdflatex`. Для EPS нужно компилировать командой `latex`, затем последовательно запускать `dvips` и `ps2pdf` с файлами dvi и ps соответственно.

Comment: Отредактируйте в наиболее общем стиле. Будет ли рисунок при использовании стандартных document-классов? Без всяких аргументов у includegraphics, figure? Привидите минимально проблемный и стандартный текст документа.

Comment: Vladimir, спасибо! Вы очень помогли!